# Roslyn compilation - how to reference a .NET Standard 2.0 class library

Tags: c#, roslyn

I created a console application project (targeting .NET Core 3.0) and a class library (targeting .NET Standard 2.0). The console application tries to use the Roslyn compiler to compile some C# code that references that previously created class library. I'm hitting some major issues though.

Here's the code for the console application (note that most of it is example code from https://github.com/joelmartinez/dotnet-core-roslyn-sample/blob/master/Program.cs):

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp; //nuget Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;

//This is a class library I made in a separate project in the solution and added as a reference to the console application project.
//The important bit for the reproduction of the issue is that ClassLibrary1 targets .NET Standard 2.0.
using ClassLibary1;

namespace RoslynIssueRepro
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string codeToCompile =
                @"
                using ClassLibary1;
                using System;

                namespace RoslynCompileSample
                {
                    public class Writer
                    {
                        public void Execute()
                        {
                            //1. this next line of code introduces the issue during Roslyn compilation (comment it out and everything runs fine).
                            //It causes the code to reference a .NET Standard 2.0 class library (and this console app targets .NET Core 3.0).
                            //Note: If the referenced class library targets .NET Core 3.0, everything works fine.
                            //The error looks like this:
                            //  CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
                            Console.WriteLine(Class1.DoStuff());

                            Console.WriteLine(""Freshly compiled code execution done!"");
                        }
                    }
                }";

            var refPaths = new[] {
                typeof(System.Object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location,
                typeof(Console).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location,
                Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(System.Runtime.GCSettings).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location), "System.Runtime.dll"),
                typeof(Class1).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location,

                //2. So adding a reference to netstandard.dll to alleviate the issue does not work.
                //Instead it causes even more compilation errors of this form:
                //  CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
                //  CS0433: The type 'Console' exists in both 'System.Console, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
                //Go ahead and try it by uncommenting the line below:
                //Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\ref\netstandard.dll")
            };

            RoslynCompileAndExecute(codeToCompile, refPaths);
        }

        #region example code from https://github.com/joelmartinez/dotnet-core-roslyn-sample/blob/master/Program.cs
    private static void RoslynCompileAndExecute(string codeToCompile, string[] refPaths)
    {
        Write("Let's compile!");

        Write("Parsing the code into the SyntaxTree");
        SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(codeToCompile);

        string assemblyName = Path.GetRandomFileName();

        MetadataReference[] references = refPaths.Select(r => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(r)).ToArray();

        Write("Adding the following references");
        foreach (var r in refPaths)
            Write(r);

        Write("Compiling ...");
        CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
            assemblyName,
            syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree },
            references: references,
            options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);

            if (!result.Success)
            {
                Write("Compilation failed!");
                IEnumerable<Diagnostic> failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
                    diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
                    diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

                foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in failures)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}", diagnostic.Id, diagnostic.GetMessage());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Write("Compilation successful! Now instantiating and executing the code ...");
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                Assembly assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(ms);
                var type = assembly.GetType("RoslynCompileSample.Writer");
                var instance = assembly.CreateInstance("RoslynCompileSample.Writer");
                var meth = type.GetMember("Execute").First() as MethodInfo;
                meth.Invoke(instance, null);
            }
        }
    }
    static Action<string> Write = Console.WriteLine;
    #endregion
    }
}
```

and the code for the ClassLibrary1 is just this:

```
namespace ClassLibary1
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        public static string DoStuff()
        {
            return "asdfjkl";
        }
    }
}
```

I've commented two places in code with //1 and //2. The first one is the line that introduces the first issue, and causes the compilation to fail. The second spot (currently commented out) is an attempt to work around the first issue by adding a reference to the netstandard.dll file (sorry if the path isn't portable, just where I happened to find it on my machine), but it does not fix anything, only introducing more cryptic errors.

Any idea on the approach I should take to get this code to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first error occur because your referenced library targets `netstandard` and the console app compilation which references this library must reference `netstandard.dll` to correctly resolve all corresponding types. So you should add reference to `nestandard.dll` but it's not all and here you get the second error.

When you try to reference `netsandard` directly or by transitive you must provide the `nestandard.dll` corresponding by the target platform. And this `netstandard` will have a huge of forwarding types to the types on the current target platform. If you look at the `@"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\ref\netstandard.dll"` you will find that this `netstandard.dll` doesn't contain forwards but contains all types directly and of course it contains `System.Console`. ( I think, it contains all types directly because it is from nuget package which doesn't depend on any target platform, but really not sure for that). And when you try to add it and `System.Console.dll` by `typeof(Console).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location` you actually get two `System.Console` in a compilation.

So to resolve this ambiguous you can add `netstandard` not from this nuget package, but from you current target platform which has all needed forwards. For the `.netcore30`, for example, you can use `netstandard` from `path_to_dotnet_sdks\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\3.0.0\ref\netcoreapp3.0\` (be careful this assemblies and assemblies from nuget package above just for referencing, they doesn't contain real logic). Also you may try to remove reference on `System.Console.dll` and keep reference on `@"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.nuget\packages\netstandard.library\2.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\ref\netstandard.dll"`

Comment: Wow, it worked! I just changed the ref path to be `@"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\3.0.0\ref\netcoreapp3.0\netstandard.dll"` rather than the path that involved ".nuget" in my original code. At that point it was able to do the dynamic compilation and run the code. Thanks! Is there a more "portable" way in which I should write that code (so that I don't have to reference a dll at some hard coded path)?

Comment: @Anssssss, well, "portable" way is just usage of a couple targets and tasks from sdk and msbuild for different platform targets for correct resolving in a common cases. For example to resolve `path_to_dotnet_sdks\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\3.0.0\ref\netcoreapp3.0\ ` for `netcore30` you may use https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/master/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets#L274. Besides for `.netframework461-472` you should use `Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions.NETFramework.targets` and it dependent targets and so on so forth.

Comment: I just did a bit of searching and don't see how to use a .targets file with my Roslyn code above. Could you give me a hint at that (or link)? Alternatively, I could ask that in a separate question (though it is fairly related to the original question).

Comment: @Anssssss, targets and tasks isn't used with Roslyn (as part of them), but is used as additional separate "logic" which allows to resolve a couple of references to use them later in the Roslyn compilation. This targets just determine how to resolve references, where them should be found and so on so forth. After you was locate all needed references you may add them to compilation. Besides, if you have `.proj` file or `.sln` file you may look at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Workspaces/Core/MSBuild/MSBuild/MSBuildWorkspace.cs. It may avoid resolving by hand in some cases.

Comment: Seriously, give George more upvotes! This man is so smart and has helped me in several situations where I didn't understand Roslyn properly.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using `typeof(X).Assembly` to locate all other referenced assemblies, which will implicitly return the assemblies loaded into your App Domain. I would recommend locating the matching netstandard in the same way. However, since netstandard doesn't directly define any types, the best method I've found is to search for it by name;

```cs
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Single(a => a.GetName().Name == "netstandard")
```

Comment: This solution returns in my case:

    C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.5

And if I use that folder it fails to compile. It does work if i use the assemblies in:

    C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\NETStandard.Library.Ref\2.1.0\ref\netstandard2.1

Answer (score 0):

```
var dd = typeof(Enumerable).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location;
var coreDir = Directory.GetParent(dd);

MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(coreDir.FullName + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "netstandard.dll")
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Path.Combine(RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), "netstandard.dll")
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32577097)